# Cisco SG220 Web Interface stops responding. Is there a way to reload it though the console?

Tags: cisco, switch

I have a Cisco SG220 and the web interface stops responding and is no longer accessible after some days of usage. This is a fairly new equipment and every time it happens the switch continues to operate normally. Every computer is able to communicate, I can access the console and work with it. Just the web interface stops working.

I'd like to know if there's a way to stop/start the web interface from the console. The only way I manage to get it back up is to reload the switch, which I don't want to do.

Bonus question: Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your time and availability!

P.S. You could invert the whole thing and make my bonus question my main one and I'd be super happy about it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just called Cisco and they told me to try connecting using HTTPS instead of HTTP. It worked like a charm.

Guess it's a problem on my end (browser maybe).

Thanks everyone and happy holidays!